# launch transmission-daemon as root

Tags: raspberry-pi, root, chmod, transmission

have trouble with transmission daemon. I need to write files to external hdd, but always get `Error: Permission denied`

Some guys write something about auto-mounting bug, but I can't mount it each time by hands (computer have no keyboard and screen, and there is different peoples can remove HDD and insert it back).

Also, I try to change USER constant from `deabian-transmission` to `pi` and to `root` inside of `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` file, but nothing happen:

```
ps -ef | grep trans
```

display

```
debian-+ 4599   1  15:52 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f
```

I'm sure that this line display transmission deamon porcess, because, it disappear after `sudo service transmission-daemon stop`.

So my question is - how I can change this user to `root`? And yes, I'm absolutely do not take care about security risks about it.

Answer (score 4):

`transmission-daemon` does not use the `USER` variable in `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` if your system is using [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd).

systemd is telling the `transmission-daemon` to run as the `debian-transmission` user in the service file `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service`.

Starting state:

```
deltik@box59:~$ ps -ef | grep transmission | grep -v grep
debian-+  8140     1  0 07:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
```

This is the proper way to override the service to start it under the `root` user:

1. `sudo systemctl edit transmission-daemon.service`
2. Add the following contents:

   ```
   [Service]
   User=root
   ```
3. Save the file.

   - `nano`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - `vi`/`vim`: <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

     <sup><sub>Note: This creates the file `/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/override.conf`</sub></sup>
4. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
5. `sudo systemctl restart transmission-daemon.service`

Now, `transmission-daemon` is running as the `root` user:

```
deltik@box59:~$ ps -ef | grep transmission | grep -v grep
root      8443     1  0 07:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
```

Comment: sorry man, I forgot to test it on weekend. I will do it today, and write response.

Comment: thanks it work, now process started as root user, but web interface not work anymore, lol

Comment: Finally I open /etc/passwd and set 0:0 to debian-transmission. Now debian-transmission is root user, and look like it work.

Comment: It copies initializes new config to ./root/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
So you just need to copy settings from older config located in ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json